# Laravel -two packages need same table name

Tags: laravel, package

Basically in Laravel5, I want to use two packages.For simplicity lets name them package1 and package2.The two packages do entirely different things.One is for post authentication ie whwether a user should be allowed to  manage a post ,a comment or the site itself,the other is for chat system

When I downloaded package1(using composer),and ran `php artisan migrate`,it ran a migration and created a table called `permissions`.

Now as I'm trying to migrate from package2 it gives me the error:

`Base table or view already exists :1050 table`permissions`already exists`...

So two packages want to use a table with the same name.

What do I do?

Comment: Are these packages created by you or are they third party packages over which you have no control?

Comment: @Bodgan  Third-party packages.If they were by me I could easily change them :-)

Comment: "The two packages do entirely different things". Is that really so? If they both need a `permissions` table, it sounds like they're doing something that the other package also does.

Comment: There is nothing you can do other than changing the package source code or checking if said packages allow you to configure the table/connection to use. If neither of those packages allow this and both these packages decided to use a table name "permissions" without allowing this then I'd say raise a case for the package authors because locking down such a common table name for themselves seems like very bad practice.

Comment: @Loek is right, if you have two packages that use the same table names, chances are the table structure is conflicting, and if it not at this point it might be in the future. So this seems like a dangerous path to go down.

Comment: @Loek One is for authentication the other is for chat system

Comment: @apokryfos so what do I do.........delete the pacakage and search for a new one

Comment: Well, if the chat system needs `permissions` table, it probably also implemented some form of Authentication/Authorizatiton. Take a look at that and then you probably delete the authentication package. Also, why would you need an authentication package? Laravel provides that out of the box.

Comment: @Loek No.This 'permission' is different.There a re four rows(or columns) which are manage post,manage users,manage comments,manage site.They are linked to user,admins,moderator and author..

Comment: If neither of the packages allows you to customise the table name and neither of the package authors is willing to write a fix then you need to find a package to do one of the two.

Comment: @Titoxdboss Sounds like they are permissions to me? They even added some roles apparently.

Comment: @apokryfos I can't start all over......I'll look for another package

Comment: @Titoxdboss, if it is publishing migrations, you may change table name after vendor:publish

Comment: Or you could fork one of the packages. If they were written well you might only have to change the table name in the migration and the mode.

Comment: @Titoxdboss, what are the names of these packages

Comment: @SomeDev Explain pls....

Comment: @SomeDev https://github.com/musonza/chat and https://github.com/madalintomescu/laravel-blog

Comment: I'm sorry.My answer got a downvote so i deleted it

Comment: Do these steps: If you are in development mode and deleting all tables doesn't affect, remove all tables from you database, republish your migration tables and migrate

Comment: @SomeDev Ok.Thanks.What is 'development mode'?

Comment: Means that you are developing it and it is not deployed yet

Comment: Chat is prefixed, no permission tables at all. When migration fails, probably can't delete the table. When you re-run the migration, the table sits there. Try to drop the tables manually and re-run it

Comment: or use `php artisan migrate:fesh` which will drop all tables and run all migrations